# Why am I getting an error fetching messages?

Tags: fetch, discord.js, message, edit

there is an error calling the script. Can you ask for help?

Below I paste the code and the error.

```js
let chn = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '717019301357420554');
let msg = chn.fetchMessage('717369584801546273');
msg.edit(embedit);
```

```js
TypeError: msg.edit is not a function
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this v11?

Regardless fetching something is async, so you need to wait for msg to resolve.

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.1.0/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage

Here's how you can go about it:

First one is using await which needs to be inside of an async function

```js
let chn = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '717019301357420554');
let msg = await chn.fetchMessage('717369584801546273');
msg.edit(embedit);
```

Second is `.then`

```js
let chn = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '717019301357420554');
chn.fetchMessage('717369584801546273').then(msg => msg.edit(embedit));
```

If you want to save it in a variable

```js
let chn = client.channels.find(channel => channel.id === '717019301357420554');
let msg;
chn.fetchMessage('717369584801546273').then(m => msg = m);
//note you will have to wait for the promise to resolve to use 
//the variable msg correctly
//any code beyond this isn't guranteed to have access to
```

These are some bad variable names btw, you shouldn't use abbreviations like `chn` rather `channel`, and `embedit` => `embEdit`. But up to you

Comment: No problem, actually there was an error with the second code, it doesn't break the code but it wasn't correct assigning (`let msg = <Promise>`), so if you were using it see the edit for better example